# Getting time difference using a time_t converted from a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the diff between two dates.
One date being right now and the other is a date converted to time_t from a string representation of a date.

My code is as follows

```
    const char *time_details = "12/03/2014";
    struct tm tm;
    strptime(time_details, "%m/%d/%Y", &tm);
    time_t mytime = mktime(&tm);

    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    double seconds = difftime(now, mytime);

    LOGG("now = %d", now);

    LOGG("mytime = %d", mytime);
    LOGG("unsigned int mytime = %d", (int)mytime);
```

My output looks like so:

```
now = 1417830679
mytime = -1
seconds = 1610001720
```

mytime always comes out to -1
And, the value for seconds is not correct either.

Comment: Did anything reasonable show up in `tm`?

Comment: What is the return value from `strptime`?

Comment: tm was valid and contained the correct values.

Comment: And, strptime returns a valid pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before use (and you might want to pick a different name for the variable)

```
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
```

See Notes section in [strptime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime)

Comment: This is it, the `mktime` fails when presented with invalid input. You don't need to use `memset`though, just do `struct tm t = {};`.